# Merge multiple webm files using avconv

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avconv, merge

I have multiple `.webm` files in one location, say as inside video folder. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 32bit system. I want to merge all my webm files in one `output.webm` file.

I have read about `ffmpeg`, but when I tried `ffmpeg` with *concat* function I got:

> `Unknown input format: 'concat'`; And ffmpeg is deprecated and use avconv instead.

Please suggest how to use `avconv` for merging multiple webm files to one.

Comment: The fake `ffmpeg` from Libav is what was deprecated for `avconv`; not `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg. Unfortunately the maintainer refused to clarify that in the message resulting in confused users (and some think it was the intended effect).

Comment: Please [download a recent ffmpeg build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) and then show some info about your inputs. It will help me provide an answer, and `avconv` doesn't have the functionality of what I'm going to suggest. Include the full output of: `ffmpeg -i input0.webm -i input1.webm -i input2.webm`, etc.

Comment: 2 questions: 1. Which version of Ubuntu are you using? 2. What are the file names of your webm files?

Comment: Ubuntu is 13.10 32bit.  No specific file names yet, you can just take file names as `one.webm`, `two.webm`, `three.webm` etc. and merge them into `merged.webm`.

Comment: @MandarPandit Support for Ubuntu 13.10 ended on 17 July 2014. You should upgrade to a supported version.

Comment: If you are not strict about tools, see with `mencoder -oac copy -ovc copy -of lavf -o merged.webm one.webm, two.webm, three.webm` . The only thing I noticed is the time shrink may be a bug or I'm missing something.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard, You are right in 16.04 it is just a link to `ffmpeg` . In 14.04, even `-i concat:..|..|.."` didn't work for me, and the only solution I could get it to work  is `mencoder` as mentioned in the above comment. May be compiling ffmpeg from source is an option.

Comment: @Sneetsher I'm guessing the concat demuxer as you suggested will work with Ubuntu 15.04 and above because that's when `ffmpeg` returned to the repositories.

Answer (score 9):

## Download

The first step is to [download `ffmpeg`](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/). It's a standalone binary so you don't need to install it. Just execute it directly.

Your (expired) Ubuntu version offers `avconv` which is missing many features including several concatenation functions.

## Concatenate

Use the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1) if you want to attempt to join them with no re-encoding. All videos must have the same parameters.

Use the [concat filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#concat) if the videos vary in width, height, frame rate, etc. The filter will require re-encoding.

<sub>**Note:** You never did provide the info I requested a year and a half ago in my comments to your question, so I can't suggest which one you specifically need to use. Also, I can't provide examples specific to your inputs without this info, so the following examples are generic and may not work without additional options.</sub>

### concat demuxer

Make a text file listing your inputs:

```
file 'input0.webm'
file 'input1.webm'
file 'input2.webm'
```

Now run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.webm
```

### concat filter

In this example `input1.webm` has a bigger *width x height* than the others. This example command will scale `input1.webm` so it matches the other videos:

```
ffmpeg -i input0.webm -i input1.webm -i input2.webm -filter_complex \
"[1:v]scale=640:-1[v1]; \
 [0:v][0:a][v1][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[v][a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.webm
```

## Also see

- [FFmpeg Wiki: Concatenate](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)

Comment: Nice to know about the static build availability , :) that's really helpful.

Comment: @Sneetsher If only someone will provide a variety of ARM builds for all of those Android users on Stack Overflow...we would see far fewer outdated 2.4.2 builds (not sure where they're all getting it from).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard: Your neck beard is indeed long :)